# Is $\mathcal{H}_\delta^\alpha$ a metric outer measure?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, hausdorff-measure

When going through a proof that $\mathcal{H}^\alpha:=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\mathcal{H}^\alpha_\delta$ is a $metric$ outer measure I found myself wondering whether for each fixed $\alpha$ and $\delta$, $\mathcal{H}^\alpha_\delta$ is also a metric outer measure. I haven't been able to prove it or find a counterexample yet. I want to believe that it's false, so I would appreciate it if someone could point an easy counterexample or, in the case that it's truly a source of proof.
Here $\mathcal{H}^\alpha_\delta(A):=inf\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty (r_j)^\alpha\ |\ A\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty B_{r_j}(z_j),\ r_j\leq\delta\ \ \ \forall j \}$ for any $A \subset\mathbb{R}^n$  And $\mathcal{H}^\alpha$ is, as it's usually called, the $\alpha$-dinensional spherical Hausdorff outer measure.

Comment: $\mathcal{H}^{a}$ is the $a$ dimensional Hausdorff measure?

Comment: Yes, I've eddited my question providing some more details

Comment: I think this says that $\mathcal{H}^\alpha$ is metric but doesnt say anything about $\mathcal{H}^\alpha_\delta$ for a fixed $\delta$ being metric. Or am I missing something

Comment: Perhaps I misread the page... You might be right, I'll remove my previous comment.

Comment: So, I've shown that it is an outer measure. A counterexample, if it exist, will fail the separation axiom for a metric outer measure.